# Print MySQL query result from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get some data from table and print or use only the data.
Failing to do both ...

```
$con=mysqli_connect($MySQL_Host,$MySQL_User,$MySQL_Password,$MySQL_DB);

function echo_func_test ($db_con,$INPUT_IndustryName){
$result = mysqli_query($db_con,"SELECT ID FROM Industries where IndustryName = '$INPUT_IndustryName'");
//$Data = mysql_fetch_row($result);
var_dump ($result);

}

$IndustryName = Utilities;
echo_func_test($con,$IndustryName);
```

=================

```
the output is:
mysqli_result::__set_state(array(
   'current_field' => NULL,
   'field_count' => NULL,
   'lengths' => NULL,
   'num_rows' => NULL,
   'type' => NULL,
))  root@virtual-dev:/home/ftpadmin/FirstPHP2# php Scripts/main.php
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to call [*mysqli_fetch_array*](http://pk1.php.net/mysqli_fetch_array) after `mysqli_query()`

Comment: `$industryName = 'Utilities'`.  You need to turn on error logging and/or error display when developing.  You also should make sure you are testing your edge cases when running queries.  Make suire you connection works, if not handle it.  Make sure you query works, if not handle it, etc.

Comment: And above all: _start reading the documentation!_ How do you expect to get a correct result if you do not know how things are meant to be used?